# Recursively touching directories' last modified datetime as the same datetime of the last modified file inside

Tags: linux, touch, recursion

Previously I have ran `dos2unix` on every `*.php` file on my server recursively with this command:

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec dos2unix --keepdate {} +
```

All files processed by `dos2unix` had its last modified datetime intact, but the parent directory containing such files still have their last modified datetime updated to the time I ran the command.

How do I, with an one liner, touch the directories recursively, setting the last modified datetime of the directories as the same datetime as the last modified file inside the directory?

From this:

```
dir_a/               2013-05-13 14:05
   abc.php           2012-09-01 12:34
   def.php           2012-09-15 23:45
   dir_b/            2013-05-13 14:05
       uvw.php       2012-10-01 01:23
       xyz.php       2012-10-08 09:10
```

To this:

```
dir_a/               2012-09-15 23:45
   abc.php           2012-09-01 12:34
   def.php           2012-09-15 23:45
   dir_b/            2012-10-08 09:10
       uvw.php       2012-10-01 01:23
       xyz.php       2012-10-08 09:10
```

The server is running on CentOS 5.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do file="$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)";if [ -n "$file" ]; then touch "$dir" -mr "$file"; fi; done
```

**Explanation:**

To pass modification date from one file to another we have to run:

```
touch file1 -mr file2
```

First we have to find subdirectories:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do echo "$dir"; done
```

In this case `-exec` option would get too complex so I use while-read approach. You need to make sure to pipe the output from `find` with `NUL` as record separator, and tell `read` to split on that (`-d ''`).

To find files with last modification date I can use:

```
find ./  -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Combining it:

```
find . -mindepth 1  -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do file="$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)";echo "$dir <- $file"; done
```

Finally, adding touch:

```
find . -mindepth 1  -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do file="$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)";touch "$dir" -mr "$file"; done
```

I use `-mindepth` option here because I launched this command from directory containing dir_a which does not have any file to read date from. To eliminate this problem I can use if-else to ensure i do not try to read time from non existing file:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do file="$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)";if [ -n "$file" ]; then touch "$dir" -mr "$file"; fi; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked almost perfectly, only failing when `touch` tries to get the last modified datetime from a file with spaces in the filename.

Comment: @Phil Yeah, that's probably because of the (broken) `$(find …)` construct in the middle. Try exchanging the `-f2` to `-f2-` and surrounding the `$()` with double quotes.

Comment: @slhck That fixed the problem with `touch`, but now I've noticed `find` is failing when a directory name contains spaces, can you point out how to fix this as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Phil True, that `find … | while` was broken as well. You need to call it with `-print0 | while read … -d ''` and quote the `"$dir"` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do 
 time=$(
  find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -c %Y {} \; | 
  sort -nk2 | tail -n 1
 ); touch -d @$time "$dir"; 
 done
```

EXPLANATION:

- `find -mindepth 1 -type d | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do` : iterate through all directories except the current one (`-mindepth 1`). Using a `while` loop with `IFS=` and the `-r` flag is to make sure the command works with directory names that contain spaces or new lines (`\n`) or other strange characters. The `-d ''` sets the delimiter to the null character so it can work with find's `-print0` option.
- `find $dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat --printf="%Y\n" {} \;` : Find all files of each directory `$dir` and run `stat` which prints their modification date in [seconds since epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
- `sort -nk2 | tail -n 1`  : this just sorts the dates and keeps the newest. The last two parts combined give the modification time of the newest file which is saved in the variable `$time`.
- `touch -d @$time $dir` : here we use the `touch` command to set the modification time of each directory. The `@` is there to tell `touch` that we a re giving time in seconds since epoch, this is a [standard GNU coreutils feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html#Seconds-since-the-Epoch).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get a lot of `touch: invalid date format \`@'` errors when I run this.

Comment: @Phil Check if `$time` contains anything after the `$(find …)` is run.   You should only get that error if `$time` is empty.

Comment: @Phil that will happen if you have directories that don't contain any files. Since the value of `$time` depends on the newest _file_ in each directory, it will be empty when the directories contain no files. This shouldn't be a problem though, just ignore those messages, you don't care about directories with no files.